# Web Deployment tools for Visual Studio 2013

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, web

I am responsible for supporting a relatively complex Website project written with .NET 3.5.

Previously I was using Web Deployment Project with Visual Studio 2010 to deploy this website but at the moment I have only access to Visual Studio 2013.

As far as I know, there is no longer such a tool to be used for deployment in Visual Studio 2013 and I do want to compile the code before deploying to the production server. As mentioned earlier, the project is a bit complex and this would not be easy to be converted to a Web Application.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I missed it, unsure what the issue is - in VS2013, `Publish` is what you are looking for (either WebSite or Application).

What exactly do you mean by *"none of the (vs 2013 publish) options worked"*? What is/was the issue?

In one of your comments, you state you want to "pre-compile" (aka "don't want to upload `.cs` source files) and that's a setting in `Publish`.

[image: Pre-compile options]

You can `Publish` to your local file system: "Custom" -> File System:

[image: Publish to fs]

Comment: Thanks man. As a matter of fact I was not using "Precompile during publishing" option because it used to generate a lot of ugly random assembly names like App_Web_9a5rnows.dll and so on (Actually that's why we used Web Deployment Tools in early versions). But right now I realized with Configure button we can force Visual Studio to create only one unified assembly (with our desired name) which seems perfectly meet my requirement.

Comment: @Mori Yup, it's all "there" (much easier now IMHO) :)

Answer (score 0):

This extension still exists for Visual Studio 2013: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/web-deploy

Comment: This is not what I want. I am looking for a tool which compiles the code of a website project and publishes deployable files on the local disc. Something exactly similar to the old Web Deployment tool.

Answer (score 0):

Little bit confused with the question because you are keep referring about website rather web application.

If you are looking to convert web site to web app then you need to follow this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/aa983476(v=vs.100).aspx

Otherwise, if you are referring about the deployment project. Yes, it is no longer available.

I'd a very similar situation like you and Since 2013 I have stopped using any deployment project, instead I have started using Publish that creates a deployment package for you on a Network , FTP, Local Drive or even on Azure.

Here is a nice guide from Microsoft

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465323(v=vs.110).aspx

If you still want to go for Deployment Project, then you would need to go for "Installshield" limited edition,which is free (http://samirvaidya.blogspot.com.au/2013/11/how-to-enable-installshield-le-for.html).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kt85ked(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, I keep referring to Website because the type my project is Website. I used to use Web Deployment tools to compile the code and publish it to the production server.
I know there is a lot of options in VS 2013 for deployment but none of them works for me. This is a big project and I don't want to make a big conversion or change because I am not paid for that.

I am looking for a tool or trick to use the same technique as we did with Web Deployment tools with earlier versions. I do not want to upload *.cs files on the production server.

Comment: I want only change a couple of code and deploy the assembly to the servers without changing other files.

Comment: Have you tried using publish option for the website ?